# An application of Cauchy-Schwarz ineq. on infinite series

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

If $\sum a_{k}^{2}9^{k}\le 5$ then $\sum |a_{k}|2^{k}\le 3$.

sums are from $0$ to $\infty$.

could you please help with this question.

Comment: It is an application of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "Schwarz" to omit the "t"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lvert a_k\rvert 2^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\lvert a_k\rvert 3^k\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k.$$

Now use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.